# Can not render "try and catch" on ejs file

Tags: javascript, ejs

I try to do render my code and do some logic by handle error by using "try and catch". But I got an error:

Everything else in my code seems to work ok with .ejs file except "try and catch"

I try with even simple example with "try and catch" but the code still don't work at all

```
<% try {console.log("Success"); %>
<% } %>
<% catch(err) {console.log("Fail"); %>
<% } %>
```

I got an error like this:

Missing catch or finally after try in /home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/views/partials/oxfordHtml.ejs while compiling ejs
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of using a try/catch is in your ejs file is ? (I'm assuming its a view), any logic like that is best done server side?

Comment: yes, it's the view page. I try to manage it's on the server side but It's a bunch of JSON data I need to render and loop through it on an HTML page. I have no idea on getting a chunk of data from the server side and render it (loop through HTML element)on the client side. So I decide to make it done on view page. Any hep would be appreciate!

Comment: Ok, i'll provide an example as an answer on how to pass data from server to view, give me 5-10 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments here is an example of how I would pass data from the server side to the view (and loop over the object)

```
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  const names = [ { first_name: 'Thuan', surname: 'Thien' }, { first_name: 'Richard', surname: 'Lewis'} ];
  res.render('about', { names });
});
```

Then in your view you have you can loop over the object like so

```
<% names.forEach((name) => { %>
  <p>First Name: <%= name.first_name %><p>
  <p> Surname: <%= name.surname %></p>
<% } %>
```

Try hardcoding something like that for now and then after just use your actual JSON object

Comment: Thank you! That's a huge help. I have done with my job now. But still cannot handle "try and catch" on the client side which I have no idea how it didn't work. Do you have any insights about this?

Comment: My understanding is that you don't use try/catch on the client side. You would do that server side when using async/await as an example. Maybe create a new question with your current issue, providing as much details as possible